# Python -m http.server 443 -- with SSL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, ssl, server

Is it possible to create a temporary Python3 HTTP server with an SSL certificate? For example:

```
$ python3 -m http.server 443 --certificate /path/to/cert
```

Answer (score 10):

Not from the command line, but it's pretty straightforward to write a simple script to do so.

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler 
import ssl
httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), BaseHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(
    httpd.socket,
    keyfile="path/to/key.pem",
    certfile='path/to/cert.pem',
    server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

[Credit](https://blog.anvileight.com/posts/simple-python-http-server/)

If you are not restricted to the standard library and can install pip packages, there are also a number of other options, for example you can install uwsgi, which accepts command line options.

Comment: Thanks! Despite "this works", it also requires to subclass ```BaseHTTPRequestHandler``` and implement your own ```do_GET``` (and ```do_POST``` if needed). Without it (plainly as in the answer), this resulted in ```Error code: 501 , Message: "Unsupported method ('GET')" , Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED - Server does not support this operation.``` in web browser for me.

Comment: You can also use `SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` if all you need is to serve files similar to `python3 -m http.server`.

Comment: replacing `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` with `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` works, it's logging out the same as `python3 -m http.server`

Comment: replacing with ```SimpleHTTPRequestHandler``` works for me too.

Answer (score 2):

Actually no, but there is an implementation that uses the same package with ssl.
You should [try it](https://gist.github.com/dergachev/7028596).

The script is written using Python 2 but it is pretty easy to implement again with Python 3 since it is 5 lines.

The http.server is the Python 3 is the equivalent to SimpleHTTPServer from Python 2.

```py
import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer
import ssl

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='./server.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Script credits to [dergachev](https://gist.github.com/dergachev/7028596)

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BaseHTTPServer'

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for.

```py
# WEBSERVER with SSL support
# Create certificate files ca_key.pem and ca_cert.pem and they should be in the same folder

# Output when client connects:
# Web Server at => 192.168.1.100:4443
# 192.168.1.22 - - [12/Feb/2022 02:32:56] "GET /default.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
import http.server
import ssl

HOST = '192.168.1.100'
PORT = 4443
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
with http.server.HTTPServer((HOST, PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("Web Server listening at => " + HOST + ":" + str(PORT))
    sslcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
    sslcontext.load_cert_chain(keyfile="ca_key.pem", certfile="ca_cert.pem")
    httpd.socket = sslcontext.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, server_side=True)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```