# Detect if connection is HTTP or HTTPS and handle it in python

Tags: python, http, sockets, ssl, https

I have a socket listening on a port and I don't know what kind of connections I'm getting on it. It can be HTTP, HTTPS or something different. I would like that my server will handle at least HTTP and HTTPS by identifying the fist bytes of traffic that it receives. I wrote some code that reads the first received byte to infer the connection type.

So far I have:

```
from enum import Enum

class PacketType(Enum):
    HTTP = 1
    HTTPS = 2
    HTTP2 = 3
    OTHER = 4
def guessPacketType(s):
    HTTP2_PREAMBLE = "PRI *m HTTP/2.0"

    firstByte = csock.recv(1)
    if firstByte == 0x16:
        return (PacketType.HTTPS, firstByte)
    elif firstByte == HTTP2_PREAMBLE[0]:
        dataRead = firstByte + csock.recv(len(HTTP2_PREAMBLE) - 1)
        if dataRead == HTTP2_PREAMBLE:
            return (PacketType.HTTP2, dataRead)
        else:
            try:
                dataRead.decode('ascii')
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                return (PacketType.OTHER, dataRead)
            else:
                return (PacketType.HTTP, dataRead)
    elif firstByte.decode() in ["G", "H", "P", "D", "C", "O", "T"]:
        # HTTP more likely
        return (PacketType.HTTP, firstByte)
    else:
        # something else
        return (PacketType.OTHER, firstByte)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import socket
    import struct

    SO_ORIGINAL_DST = 80


    s = socket.socket()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 2000))
    s.listen(10)

    while True:
        csock, caddr = s.accept()
        orig_dst = csock.getsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST, 16)

        packetType, readBytes = guessPacketType(csock)

        data = bytearray()
        while True:
            packet = csock.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            data.extend(packet)

        csock.close()

        orig_port = struct.unpack('>H', orig_dst[2:4])
        orig_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(orig_dst[4:8])

        print('connection from', caddr)
        print('connection to', (orig_addr, orig_port))
```

How can I handle an SSL connection as soon as I detect that the client is requesting SSL? I've checked the [SSL/TLS socket wrapper library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) but it seems you need to create a SSL wrapped socket before listening which for my case I can't. For HTTP I can just read the entire data and parse it out later but what about SSL? How do should I do the TLS negotiation.

I've [based my code on this post](https://httptoolkit.com/blog/http-https-same-port/).

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `recv` with `socket.MSG_PEEK` to find out the first byte without removing it from the socket buffer. Then you can use a normal `ssl.wrap_socket` since everything is still in the socket buffer.

Comment: You can't seriously be proposing in this day and age to implement an HTTP/HTTPS server from scratch. There is no shortage of existing freeware that already works. You probably have no idea of the complexity of this task/

Comment: @user207421 tell me just one existent python library to spin up a webserver that does what I'm trying to do. Not creating a simple webserver but one that listens on the same port for http and https requests.

Comment: Thank you @SteffenUllrich. That looks exactly like what I would need. I'm gonna implement it and if it works I'll answer with the solution.

Comment: @user1618465: *"Not creating a simple webserver but one that listens on the same port for http and https requests."* - Unless you do this just for curiosity I would recommend against it. There is a reason these protocols are usually served on different ports and that they also have different default ports. And while there are protocols which support both plain and encrypted on the same port this is usually done with an explicit command, like with STARTTLS in SMTP.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I agree with you but for the project I'm working on it requires from this "hacky" means to be used

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56503241/238704).